# What does cube $[0,1]^{400}$ in Euclidean space refer to?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology

Can you please help me understand the following sentence:

Suppose we accumulate many millions of image patches, each of size 20×20 pixels, Clearly, every such image is a point in $R^{400}$. Let’s put these points in this 400-dim Euclidean space, in the cube $[0,1]^{400}$.

Can someone help me understand the last sentence? What does it mean to put in $400$-dim Euclidean space and in particular, the cube $[0,1]^{400}$?? I failed to picture this in my mind!

Comment: Do you know how Cartesian products work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that all coordinates in the $400$-long vector of reals must lie in $[0,1]$.

You don't need a picture, just a vector space of $400$ dimensions: all sequences $(x_1, x_2 ,\ldots,x_{400})$ of real numbers, with coordinatewise addition and scalar multiplication. The usual Pythagorean distance formula also applies.

Comment: Does it mean all coordinates have value between [0, 1]? Are they forming basis? what does cube represent?

Comment: @fery Yes, all coordinates between $0$ and $1$. The set of all such vectors contains a basis, e.g. all unit vectors $e_1, \ldots, e_{400}$, but that's irrelevant. $[0,1]^2$ is a square in the plane, $[0,1]^3$ is just a cube in $3$-space, so this set is the analogue of that in higher dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. To me the sentence sounds rather topological language. That's why i failed to understand!!